# How to reassign values in a js object based on the values present in an object within the same object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I have an array of objects in the following form-

```
let result = [
    {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: 3,
        newValues: {
            a: 10,
            b: 20,
            c: 30
        }
    },
    {
        d: 4,
        e: 5,
        f: 6,
        newValues: {
            d: 40,
            e: 50,
            f: 60
        }
    }
]
```

And want to convert it to following format -

```
let result = [
    {
        a: 10,
        b: 20,
        c: 30,
    },
    {
        d: 40,
        e: 50,
        f: 60
    }
]
```

But have been unable to do so.
Any help for converting the older array to the new one will be very much appreciated.

Comment: `result = result.map(({ newValues }) => newValues)`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

A simple `map` will do it

```js
let result = [
    {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: 3,
        newValues: {
            a: 10,
            b: 20,
            c: 30
        }
    },
    {
        d: 4,
        e: 5,
        f: 6,
        newValues: {
            d: 40,
            e: 50,
            f: 60
        }
    }
]

let data = result.map( r => r.newValues)
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem by mapping only the r.newValues is you can potentially lost data that never changed and are not in newValues.

```js
const result = [
        {
            a: 1,
            b: 2,
            c: 3,
            newValues: {
                a: 10,
                b: 20,
                c: 30
            }
        },
        {
            d: 4,
            e: 5,
            f: 6,
            newValues: {
                d: 40,
                e: 50
            }
        }
    ];

    const updates = result.map(element => {
       const {newValues, rest} = element;
       delete element.newValues;
       
       return {...element, ...newValues};
    });
    console.log(updates);
```

It will work even if a value of newValues was not present into newValues.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is roughly equivalent to the one by JStw, with two key differences:

1. It uses Underscore instead of spread syntax;
2. It does not modify the elements of `result`.

This means that code is easier to reason about and potentially safer. Also, you don't need polyfills for the spread syntax.

```js
const result = [
    {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: 3,
        newValues: {
            a: 10,
            b: 20,
            c: 30
        }
    },
    {
        d: 4,
        e: 5,
        f: 6,
        newValues: {
            d: 40,
            e: 50
        }
    }
];

const updates = _.map(result, element =>
    _.chain(element)
    .omit('newValues')
    .extend(element.newValues)
    .value()
);

console.log(updates);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.13.6/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
```